# Annotated games in the Makogonov Grünfeld?

Tags: opening, master-games, grunfeld-defense

I would appreciate references to sources, be they books or any other sort of media, that contain annotated games in the Makogonov Variation of the Grünfeld Defense (two possible move-orders for which are given below):

```
[FEN ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.e3 (4.Nf3 Bg7 5.e3 O-O 6.b4) Bg7 5.b4
```

I would imagine that some books specifically on the Grünfeld would have what I'm after, but I don't know that literature well at all, and the couple I've looked at don't have tons of info. For instance, [*The Kaufman Repertoire for Black & White*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9056913719) proposes the Grünfeld against `1.d4`, but the sum total of its coverage of the Makogonov (unless I missed something) is to give the following single line assessment, with no words or additional analysis:

```
[FEN ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.e3 Bg7 5.Nf3 O-O 6.b4 c6 7.Bb2 a5 8.b5 a4 9.Ba3 Be6 $10
```

I mention that only as a fact, not as criticism, since the Makogonov doesn't seem to be regarded as a critical test for the Grünfeld, and Kaufman has to choose where to focus.

Avrukh's [*Grandmaster Repertoire 8: Grünfeld Defence, Volume One*](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/1/103/grandmaster_repertoire_8_-_the_grunfeld_defence_volume_one_by_boris_avrukh/) gives more to chew on, offering 4+ solid pages on the Makogonov in tree-of-variations form, and it mentions a handful of games where some of the lines come from. But still, that's not quite what I'm after; I'd like to find some Makogonov Variation games that are annotated *qua* complete games, in order to get a "feel" for this variation. So, to recap:

> Can someone point me to some complete, annotated games in the Makogonov Grünfeld?

Comment: To make the search more challenging, Ed is a USCF Expert, so he probably doesn't need B-player annotations. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[chesspublishing.com](http://www.chesspublishing.com/) has seven well-annotated (by GMs Glenn Flear and Neil McDonald) games starting with 1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.e3 Bg7 5.Nf3 O-O 6.b4, ranging from 1999 to 2009. They're not free, though.

The games are:

- Rabrenovic - Atalik 1999
- Aleksandrov - Oral 2000
- Bruzon Batista - Sutovsky 2004
- Suvrajit - Harika 2004
- Georgiev - Holzke 2007
- Akobian - Perelshteyn 2007
- Akobian - Ponomariov 2009

All have lots of verbal annotations and variations, at about the level of detail you'd expect to see in a opening book that is organized by annotated games.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Can you share any more info, e.g. players involved in the contests? I doubt that I'd shell out their subscription fee just to get these 7 games, no matter who the players are, but I *know* I won't without knowing. :)

Comment: I have added more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chess.com has a few hundred examples:

http://www.chess.com/games/results?e=776&ml=MS5kNCBOZjYgMi5jNCBnNiAzLk5jMyBkNSA0Lk5mMyBCZzcgNS5lMyBPLU8gNi5iNA%3D%3D

Comment: Are any of them annotated?